# Can a function have Range of $\mathbb R$ and Domain the subset of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Can a function $f(x)$ has the Range $R$ and Domain be the subset of $R$. For example can a function $f(x)$ has it's Range belong to  $R$ and Domain be $x\ge0$. I can't think of any such function, can you please give me an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does $R$ mean $\Bbb R$?

Comment: yup,I am a idiot

Comment: You can take $f(x)=x\sin(x)$.

Comment: Tan(x) for just 2pi interval

Comment: think of log x....?

Comment: If you insist on $x\ge 0$, then @JoséCarlosSantos solution works, but you really need to say $f(x)=\begin{cases}x\sin x&x\ge 0\\\text{undefined}&x<0\end{cases}$. Or... Use some other way to restrict the domain, e.g. $f(x)=\sqrt{x}\sin x$.